# Vertical dot navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I implemented vertical dot navigation following the idea [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/ram0Ly92/33/).
But can't figure out why
(1)when I hover the dot, it should show the label. But now it doesn't.
(2)the active dot should have rgb(207, 219, 218) color. But it doesn't.

My codes are shown below.

html

```
<form  class="summarybackground" name="summary"  id="summary" style="height:550px;width:920px;overflow-y:auto;"  method="post">

<div class="myBox" id="section"> 

    <div class="vNav">
      <ul class="vNav">
          <li> <a href="#section1"><div class="label">Landed</div></a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#section2"><div class="label">Apartment</div></a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#section3"><div class="label"> Condominium </div></a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#section4"><div class="label"> Commercial </div></a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#section5"><div class="label"> Farm </div></a>

          </li>
      </ul>


   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-9">



      <div id="section1">    
        <h1>Landed</h1>

      </div>
      <div id="section2"> 
        <h1>Apartment</h1>

      </div>
      <div id="section3">         
        <h1>Condominium</h1>

      </div>

      <div id="section4">         
        <h1>Commercial</h1>

      </div> 

      <div id="section5">         
        <h1>Farm</h1>

      </div>


   </div>



</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var parPosition = [];
    $('.par').each(function () {
        parPosition.push($(this).offset().top);
    });

    $('a').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });

    $('.vNav ul li a').click(function () {
        $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $('.vNav a').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.label').show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.label').hide();
    });

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var position = $(document).scrollTop(),
            index;
        for (var i = 0; i < parPosition.length; i++) {
            if (position <= parPosition[i]) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $('.vNav ul li a:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
    }).scroll();

    $('.vNav ul li a').click(function () {
        $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

css

```
.vNav {
    position:absolute;
    right:5%;
    top:40%;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 9999;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.vNav ul {
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px;
    padding-left: 35%;
}
.vNav ul li {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 35%;
    color: rgb(113, 135, 133);
}
.vNav a {
    display: block;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: rgb(113, 135, 133);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.vNav a:hover {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(113, 135, 133);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.vNav a.active {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(207, 219, 218);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.label {
    position:absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: rgb(113, 135, 133);
    display: none;
}


  div.col-sm-9 div {
      height: 500px;
      font-size: 28px;
  }
  #section1 {color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section2 {color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section4 {color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section5 {color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
```

EDIT 1:

```
<script  src="mainpage.js"></script>
<script 
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var parPosition = [];
    $('.par').each(function () {
        parPosition.push($(this).offset().top);
    });

    $('a').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });

    $('.vNav ul li a').click(function () {
        $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $('.vNav a').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.label').show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.label').hide();
    });

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var position = $(document).scrollTop(),
            index;
        for (var i = 0; i < parPosition.length; i++) {
            if (position <= parPosition[i]) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $('.vNav ul li a:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
    }).scroll();

    $('.vNav ul li a').click(function () {
        $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT 2:

```
<script 
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var parPosition = [];
    $('.par').each(function () {
        parPosition.push($(this).offset().top);
    });

    $('a').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });

    $('.vNav ul li a').click(function () {
        $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $('.vNav a').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.label').show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.label').hide();
    });

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var position = $(document).scrollTop(),
            index;
        for (var i = 0; i < parPosition.length; i++) {
            if (position <= parPosition[i]) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $('.vNav ul li a:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
    }).scroll();

    $('.vNav ul li a').click(function () {
        $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
</script>       
<script  src="mainpage.js"></script>
```

mainpage.js is

```
//This is for Search Menu
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#maintopmenu .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
            var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
            jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
});
$(function() {
        $( "#maintopmenu" ).tabs();
});



function searchButtonAction() {
        var min_price= $('#min_price').val();
        if ($.trim(min_price) == '' ) {
            $('#price-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#price-error').html('Please include minimum price');
            return;

        }else if(!min_price.match(/^\d+$/)){
             $('#price-error').css('display', 'block');
             $('#price-error').html('Price can include only numerical digits');
             return;
        }else{
            $('#price-error').html('');
        }  

        var max_price= $('#max_price').val();
        if ($.trim(max_price) == '' ) {
            $('#price-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#price-error').html('Please include maximum price');
            return;
        }else if(!max_price.match(/^\d+$/)){
             $('#price-error').css('display', 'block');
             $('#price-error').html('Price can include only numerical digits');
             return;
        }else{
            $('#price-error').html('');
        }  
}
```

Comment: you have an unclosed div in your html, but anyway 2) seems ok to me in chrome browser

Comment: dude, not sure what the problem is, but how are you testing this? I can see the behaviior you described perfeclty in your fiddle. I'm using Chromium 47.0.2526.106 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)

Comment: point (1) and (2) works fine in chrome! tested with your code

Comment: @EmanueleParisio it is strange. Please look at here (http://myanmarpropertiesforum.com/#section5). It doesn't show any label and color is changed in active. If I arranged in EDIT 1:, mainpage.js is above the JQuery, it shows the labels and color changed in active, but it doesn't page scroll in pressing dots. If I arranged in EDIT 2:, if JQuery code is above the mainpage.js, it doesn't show label or doesn't change color, but it does page scrolling. What is wrong?

Comment: @Joum it is strange. Please look at here (myanmarpropertiesforum.com/#section5). It doesn't show any label and color is changed in active. If I arranged in EDIT 1:, mainpage.js is above the JQuery, it shows the labels and color changed in active, but it doesn't page scroll in pressing dots. If I arranged in EDIT 2:, if JQuery code is above the mainpage.js, it doesn't show label or doesn't change color, but it does page scrolling. What is wrong?

Comment: "<script" is not closed as tag and js breaks up

Comment: @EmanueleParisio y thanks. Changed already. But still the same.

Comment: another error here: "<script>  src="mainpage.js"></script>" probably the file that load the script, the ">" after first script, and i see that you have 2 head and html tag in the same file, you should reorder all the html and read more about it and the tag position ( there are also meta tag in the body )

Comment: @EmanueleParisio thanks. But please look at this link (http://myanmarpropertiesforum.com). Now all labels and active colours are working now. Just that when you click the dot, the whole page's scroll bar is scrolling. Rather than the form's scroll bar. Because  I put all components inside summary form. I want the summary form's scroll bar is scrolling. Now looks the whole page's scroll bar is scrolling. How can I change back?

Comment: Solved. I need to change $('html, body').animate to $('form').animate.

Comment: Please look at here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824198/color-doesnt-change-at-active-dot-in-vertical-dot-navigation) for the final solution.