# Color doesn't change at active dot in vertical dot navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I implemented vertical dot navigation.
(1)The problem is the active dot's color is not changed to white. Just the first one is kept with white color though it is not active as shown in figure [image: (fig)].
(2)How can I bring down the dot positions? I tried at position, right and top properties, but not changed.

```
.vNav {
    position:absolute;
    right:7px;
    top:200px;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 9999;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

My `HTML` is

```
<form  class="summarybackground" name="summary"  id="summary" style="height:500px;width:920px;overflow-y:hidden;"  method="post">

<div class="myBox" id="section"> 

    <div class="vNav">
      <ul class="vNav">
          <li> <a href="#section1"><div class="label">Landed</div></a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#section2"><div class="label">Apartment</div></a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#section3"><div class="label"> Condominium </div></a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#section4"><div class="label"> Commercial </div></a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#section5"><div class="label"> Farm </div></a>

          </li>
      </ul>


   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div id="section1" class="par">    
        <h1>Landed</h1>

      </div>
      <div id="section2" class="par"> 
        <h1>Apartment</h1>

      </div>
      <div id="section3" class="par">         
        <h1>Condominium</h1>

      </div>

      <div id="section4" class="par">         
        <h1>Commercial</h1>

      </div> 

      <div id="section5" class="par">        
        <h1>Farm</h1>

      </div>
   </div>   



</div>

</form>
```

Javascript is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var parPosition = [];
    $('.par').each(function () {
        parPosition.push($('form').offset().top);
    });

    $('a').click(function () {
        $('form').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr('form', 'href')).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });

    $('.vNav ul li a').click(function () {
        $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $('form').addClass('active');
    });

    $('.vNav a').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.label').show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.label').hide();
    });

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var position = $('form').scrollTop(),
            index;
        for (var i = 0; i < parPosition.length; i++) {
            if (position <= parPosition[i]) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $('.vNav ul li a:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
    }).scroll();

    $('.vNav ul li a').click(function () {
        $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $(form).addClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS is

```
.summarybackground {background-color:#000000;}

.myBox {
border: none;
padding: 5px;
font: 24px/36px sans-serif;
width: 850px;
height: 500px;
margin-bottom: 150%;
}


.vNav {
    position:absolute;
    right:7px;
    top:200px;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 9999;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.vNav ul {
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px;
    padding-left: 35%;
}
.vNav ul li {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 35%;
    color: rgb(113, 135, 133);
}
.vNav a {
    display: block;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: rgb(113, 135, 133);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.vNav a:hover {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(113, 135, 133);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.vNav a.active {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.label {
    position:absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: none;
}


  div.col-sm-9 div {
      height: 500px;
      font-size: 28px;
  }

  #section1 {color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section2 {color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section4 {color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section5 {color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
```

Comment: Could you create a code snippet?

Comment: @Gothdo It is here (https://jsfiddle.net/Thomas_nyan/5bcttpe9/)

Comment: I think you have a problem with your `scrollTop`, I don't understand what are you trying to do there. BTW, you need to include the jQuery library in your fiddle.

Comment: @azeós thanks added. Why scrollTop has problem? I think it is necessary.

Comment: I don't understand this `$($.attr('form', 'href')).offset().top`.

Answer (score 0):

Removed class='vNav' from UL tag.

changed background to red for active link, as I could not place the link dots above black background.

css:

```
        .vNav a.active {
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #ff0000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('.vNav > ul > li > a').click(function() {
                $('.vNav > ul > li > a').removeClass();
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });

        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can manage to make the things work. My solution is as follow.
HTML

```
<nav id="cd-vertical-nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a data-number="1" href="#section1" class="is-selected">
                    <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                    <span class="cd-label">Landed</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-number="2" href="#section2" class="">
                    <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                    <span class="cd-label">Apartment</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-number="3" href="#section3" class="">
                    <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                    <span class="cd-label">Condominium</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-number="4" href="#section4" class="">
                    <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                    <span class="cd-label">Commercial</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-number="5" href="#section5">
                    <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                    <span class="cd-label">Farm</span>
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
</nav>
<div class="col-sm-9">
      <div id="section1">    
        <h1 class="header">Landed</h1>

      </div>
      <div id="section2"> 
        <h1 class="header">Apartment</h1>

      </div>
      <div id="section3">         
        <h1 class="header">Condominium</h1>

      </div>

      <div id="section4">         
        <h1 class="header">Commercial</h1>

      </div> 

      <div id="section5">        
        <h1 class="header">Farm</h1>

      </div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
#cd-vertical-nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4%;
  top: 65%;
  bottom: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
#cd-vertical-nav li {
  text-align: right;
  list-style:none;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  /* prevent weird movements on hover when you use a CSS3 transformation - webkit browsers */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.6);
  -o-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:hover span {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:hover .cd-label {
  opacity: 1;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a.is-selected .cd-dot {
  background-color: white;
}
#cd-vertical-nav .cd-dot {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d88683;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
#cd-vertical-nav .cd-label {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: .4em .5em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}


h1.header{
    color: green;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
}
div.col-sm-9 div {
      height: 500px;
      font-size: 18px;

}

#section1 {color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
#section2 {color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
#section3 {color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
#section4 {color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
#section5 {color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
$('a').click(function () {
        $('a').removeClass('is-selected');
        $(this).addClass('is-selected');
    });
</script>
```